# ServiceControllerStatus not giving me current status

Tags: c#

I'm getting a service controller for one of my services:

```
foreach (ServiceController sc in ServiceController.GetServices())
{
    if (sc.ServiceName == ConfigurationManager.SYNC_SERVICE_NAME)
    {
        this._serviceController = sc;
        break;
    }
}
```

and then calling the status function on it when the user triggers an action:

```
private void tsmiStartServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_serviceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)                    
        this._serviceController.Start();
}
```

However, even when the service is stopped, the status will show up as running. In fact, the status does not seem to change at all leading me to think it is detected and cached at the point I get the service controller object.

However, I've found that if I put a Refresh() call before the call to the Status property, it will detect the correct state of the service. This seems to contradict what the doco says about the call "Gets the status of the service that is referenced by this instance." unless I'm no longer referencing the correct instance somehow... ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the [`Refresh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.refresh.aspx) method on the `ServiceController` to ensure that you have the current state:

```
private void tsmiStartServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _serviceController.Refresh();
    if (_serviceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)                    
        this._serviceController.Start();
}
```

Comment: As I said in the last paragraph of the question, this does 'work' but seems to defeat the purpose of having a status property which is meant to give me the status of the service rather than a cached version of the status? If that makes sense... Also I check the status in multiple places, seems like alot of code duplication.

Comment: @Joe: sorry, I missed that part. But I completely agree with you; the documentation is confusing. Regarding checking the status in multiple places: this sounds like there is room for some refactoring. You could easily provide a static method somewhere encapsulating this behavior, which would reduce code duplication.

Comment: I'm totally flabbergasted at the design decision of making the status not refreshing. If i wanted a cache, I'd cache it in my own code (god knows why I'd want to cache the outdated status in the first place). <End Rant> Accepting your answer in defeat.